# Can I disable type-checking entirely on GHC, in order to use it as a compile-target for functional languages?

Tags: haskell, types, compilation, ghc

GHC is astonishingly fast at this point. I'm not happy with Haskell's type system, though, so I decided to implement my own as a DSL. Now, I would like to compile my language to Haskell by translating the post-checking untyped lambda calculus expressions, in order to use GHC's performance. The only problem is that some valid expressions on my system won't compile on GHC. How can I circumvent this problem - i.e., disabling the type system entirely by telling GHC "I've already checked this, trust me"?

Comment: Maybe `-fdefer-type-errors`?

Comment: Note that GHC's performance has a bit to do with the type checking: it knows what stuff is, what types are equivalent, and can apply high-level optimisations accordingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can stick an [`unsafeCoerce`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Unsafe-Coerce.html#v:unsafeCoerce) in front of every subterm (or, if you're feeling ambitious, only the ones that actually need it).

In the comments, you ask how to annotate this term to make it type-check:

```
div = (\ v0 -> (\ v1 -> (\ v2 -> (\ v3 -> ((v1 (\ v4 -> (v4 v3))) ((v0 (((v1 (\ v4 -> (\ v5 -> (\ v6 -> (v4 (\ v7 -> ((v5 v7) v6))))))) (\ v4 -> v4)) (\ v4 -> (\ v5 -> (v5 (v2 v4)))))) (((v1 (\ v4 -> (\ v5 -> v4))) (\ v4 -> v4)) (\ v4 -> v4))))))))
```

I ran `:s/(/unsafeCoerce (/g` in vim, resulting in this term:

```
div = unsafeCoerce (\ v0 -> unsafeCoerce (\ v1 -> unsafeCoerce (\ v2 -> unsafeCoerce (\ v3 -> unsafeCoerce (unsafeCoerce (v1 unsafeCoerce (\ v4 -> unsafeCoerce (v4 v3))) unsafeCoerce (unsafeCoerce (v0 unsafeCoerce (unsafeCoerce (unsafeCoerce (v1 unsafeCoerce (\ v4 -> unsafeCoerce (\ v5 -> unsafeCoerce (\ v6 -> unsafeCoerce (v4 unsafeCoerce (\ v7 -> unsafeCoerce (unsafeCoerce (v5 v7) v6))))))) unsafeCoerce (\ v4 -> v4)) unsafeCoerce (\ v4 -> unsafeCoerce (\ v5 -> unsafeCoerce (v5 unsafeCoerce (v2 v4)))))) unsafeCoerce (unsafeCoerce (unsafeCoerce (v1 unsafeCoerce (\ v4 -> unsafeCoerce (\ v5 -> v4))) unsafeCoerce (\ v4 -> v4)) unsafeCoerce (\ v4 -> v4))))))))
```

This loads in ghci, though I have no idea whether it works (or even if I should expect it to).

Edit: after a bit of inspection, this probably isn't really a fair/correct way to throw in coercions. (In particular, it leads to subterms like `v1 unsafeCoerce (\v4 -> ...)` -- and we shouldn't be passing `unsafeCoerce` as an argument anywhere.) A more correct insertion is to insert an `unsafeCoerce` at each application point, like this:

```
div = (\ v0 -> (\ v1 -> (\ v2 -> (\ v3 -> (unsafeCoerce (v1 (\ v4 -> (unsafeCoerce v4 v3))) (unsafeCoerce (v0 (unsafeCoerce (unsafeCoerce (unsafeCoerce v1 (\ v4 -> (\ v5 -> (\ v6 -> (unsafeCoerce v4 (\ v7 -> (unsafeCoerce (unsafeCoerce v5 v7) v6))))))) (\ v4 -> v4)) (\ v4 -> (\ v5 -> (unsafeCoerce v5 (unsafeCoerce v2 v4)))))) (unsafeCoerce (unsafeCoerce (unsafeCoerce v1 (\ v4 -> (\ v5 -> v4))) (\ v4 -> v4)) (\ v4 -> v4))))))))
```

Comment: Hey you again, thank you. If (and only if) you have the time, please consider illustrating your answer for completion! For example, I tried compiling [this](http://lpaste.net/130568) program by adding `unsafeCoerce` before `div`, but I guess that is not what you meant.

Comment: @Viclib, I'm told the Agda compiler does this. It's rather poor form, I would say.

Comment: Yes, this is what Agda's Haskell-targeting MAlonzo compiler backend does.  It's indeed not the cleanest approach.

Comment: Once you do this I guess you need to add an explicit annotation to each class member call. E.g. `show (unsafeCoerce x)` cannot possibly work as it is.

Comment: Note also that if you say "I've already checked this, trust me", and it turns out you were actually *wrong*... well, undefined behaviour awaits. But you knew that. ;-)

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid what do you mean?

Comment: @dfeuer @DominiqueDevriese same - what do you mean? Is it about the `div` combinator? If you have a better one please let me know :)

Comment: @Viclib Okay, so illustrated.

Comment: @DanielWagner, sorry for asking this so much later, but is there any performance weight in using `unsafeCoerce` everywhere, as opposed to only on where it is needed? I guess it is erased on runtime, right?

Comment: @Viclib It is probably erased provided it is applied to something; though it can certainly be passed around as an argument in which case it probably exists at runtime.